# Recharacterizing excess Roth IRA contribution more than once

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, roth-ira, excess-contribution

I realized that I have made excess Roth IRA contributions for 2019. I recharacterized $X as contributions to my Traditional IRA. As I was filling out my tax form, it turns out I did not sufficiently recharacterized enough (i.e. $X was too small). Does anyone know if I can go in and recharacterize $Y amount more of my excess Roth IRA contributions as contributions to Traditional IRA after already recharacterizing $X amount?

In other words, is it possible for me to continuously recharacterize my Roth IRA contributions for 2019 as Traditional IRA contributions until I get the right amount recharacterized?

I am doing all of this before I file my tax and fortunately I have until July 15th now.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that that should be fine. You recharacterized part of your contribution, and you are now recharacterizing another part of your contribution.